# Client java code fails running when server Tom Cat is not running in REST or check if server is on from client in REST

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I am new to web services. I am using Rest

Trying to connect the url

```
http://localhost:8080/CrunchifyRESTJerseyExample/crunchify/ctofservice/22
```

from a client java program

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;


public class CrunchifyRESTJerseyNetURLClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("\n============Output:============ \n"
                + callURL("http://localhost:8080/CrunchifyRESTJerseyExample/crunchify/ctofservice/22"));
    }

    public static String callURL(String myURL) {
        System.out.println("Requested URL: " + myURL);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        URLConnection urlConn = null;
        InputStreamReader in = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(myURL);
            urlConn = url.openConnection();
            if (urlConn != null)
                urlConn.setReadTimeout(60 * 1000);
            if (urlConn != null && urlConn.getInputStream() != null) {//checked hear 
                in = new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream(), Charset.defaultCharset());
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(in);
                if (bufferedReader != null) {
                    int cp;
                    while ((cp = bufferedReader.read()) != -1) {
                        sb.append((char) cp);
                    }
                    bufferedReader.close();
                }
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Exception while calling URL:" + myURL, e);
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

The code runs fine on active server ie when tomcat is running.

But problem is when the server is not running.

It is throwing an exception like:

```
Requested URL: http://localhost:8080/CrunchifyRESTJerseyExample/crunchify/ctofservice/22
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while calling URL:http://localhost:8080/CrunchifyRESTJerseyExample/crunchify/ctofservice/22
    at com.crunchify.client.CrunchifyRESTJerseyNetURLClient.callURL(CrunchifyRESTJerseyNetURLClient.java:40)
    at com.crunchify.client.CrunchifyRESTJerseyNetURLClient.main(CrunchifyRESTJerseyNetURLClient.java:14)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.crunchify.client.CrunchifyRESTJerseyNetURLClient.callURL(CrunchifyRESTJerseyNetURLClient.java:27)
    ... 1 more
```

I have checked

```
if (urlConn != null)
if (urlConn != null && urlConn.getInputStream() != null)
```

But still the code gets executed throwing exception 
Kindly help 
what needs to be handled .

Comment: Please let me know my mistake . in spite of down-vote

Answer (score 0):

You can access a web URL only if the server on which it is deployed is in running state. It is true for all the web pages and APIs that exists.

If you want to display some meaningful message or do some other work in case the API is not reachable, then don't `throw` the error (You are throwing `throw new RuntimeException("Exception while calling URL:" + myURL, e);` in the `catch` block.) or `catch` the thrown error in the calling method ie in `main` method. In the `catch` block you can just print some message on console or call alternate API that displays user friendly message.

Comment: i completely agree with you,But my question was to prevent the code if server if off. do you have a solution

Comment: i dont want to catch the error. but i want it to be handled before execution ie checking with if else

Comment: `url.openConnection();` throws exception when a particular URL is not reachable. So you have to at least do exception handling for checking if the API is reachable or not. I don't think it is possible without exception handling.